# How To Filter a list in String with MDX

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

Goal:
Filter the value in the table column based on string "Canada" as a criteria.

Problem:
I cannot get the MDX syntax code in where state to be correct in order to filter the data based on `Canada`.

Information:

- This situation is a simplified sample and my request is to add filter criteria in the where state.
- Data source is SSAS:s AdventureWorksDW2012

Code:

```
SELECT
{ 
    [Measures].[Reseller Order Count], 
    [Measures].[Discount Amount] 

} ON COLUMNS, 
{ 
    ([Reseller].[Reseller Type].[Business Type].ALLMEMBERS ) 
} ON ROWS 
FROM  [Adventure Works]
WHERE
(
    FILTER
    (
                [Geography].[Country].ALLMEMBERS, [Geography].[Country].NAME ='Canada'
    )
)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. In Adventure Works, the `Geography` dimension is not linked to the `Internet Sales` measure group. Have a look at the cube definition, tab "Dimension Usage". You should use the hierarchies from the `Customer` dimension found in the `Location` folder when using measures from the `Internet Sales` measure group. I use `[Customer].[Country]` below.
2. In a filter, you should use `Current` and a set alias to refer to the current element during the iteration of the set.

The following shows what you want, I just changed the `Filter`:

```
SELECT
{ 
    [Measures].[Reseller Order Count], 
    [Measures].[Discount Amount] 

} ON COLUMNS, 
{ 
    ([Reseller].[Reseller Type].[Business Type].ALLMEMBERS ) 
} ON ROWS 
FROM  [Adventure Works]
WHERE
(
    FILTER
    (
                [Customer].[Country].ALLMEMBERS as c, c.current.NAME ='Canada'
    )
)
```